# Change the selected option for every html select element in a class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the selected option for a group of html select elements. I have given them all the same class so that I could use jQuery to select them all at once, but for some reason it only changes the first element in the class. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bwhitney/xP4FP/1/

Here is just the code:

```
<select id="config1" class="config">
<option>foo</option>
<option selected>bar</option>
</select>

<select id="config2" class="config">
<option>foo</option>
<option selected>bar</option>
</select>

<select id="config3" class="config">
<option>foo</option>
<option selected>bar</option>
</select>
```

With the jQuery:

```
$('.config option:eq(0)').attr('selected', 'selected');​
```

The result of this code is that only the first select element will have the `foo` option selected. The second and third will still have `bar` selected. I thought that using jQuery to select a class would select all items having that class. Is there some way to select all three of these with one selector?

As a pre-emptive response to a likely answer (I'm sure *someone* will think to suggest this):
I know that I can just write a for loop to select each `$('#config' + i)`. This is what I will end up doing if there is no way to just select them all at once.

Comment: use a looping mechanism to loop thru all matches. See http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `nth-child`:

```
$('select option:nth-child(1)').prop('selected', 'selected');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/K4mnx/

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
$('.config option:eq(0)').attr('selected', 'selected');​
```

You have to use

```
$('.config option:nth-child(1)').attr('selected', 'selected');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

The fundamental difference between `:eq()` and `:nth-child()` is that

### :eq()

```
Select the element at index n within the matched set.
```

The elements are first matched based on the expression that precedes `:eq()` i.e. `.config option` in your case.

If you do a `console.log($('.config option'));` you get the following

```
[ <option>​foo​</option>​, <option selected>​bar​</option>​, <option>​foo​</option>​, <option selected>​bar​</option>​, <option>​foo​</option>​, <option selected>​bar​</option> ​]
```

And `:eq(0)` filters this matched set and hence just returns the very first element, i.e. `<option>foo</option>`.

### :nth-child()

```
Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent.
```

With `:nth-child()` the parent element is taken into consideration while filtering.

The difference is best demonstrated by the following commands

```
console.log($('.config option:eq(0)'));
```

and

```
console.log($('.config option:nth-child(1)'));
```

The first command, as expected, returns `[<option>​foo​</option>​]` as it is the 1st element of the matched set of elements.

The second command, returns

```
[ <option>​foo​</option>​, <option>​foo​</option>​, <option>​foo​</option>​ ]
```

as it selects all 1st children of `.config` of type `option`.

All the other answers are ofcourse absolutely correct.

I just thought I'd add a bit of explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.each()` this:

```
$('.config').each(function(index){
    $(this).children('option:eq(0)').attr('selected', 'selected')
});
```

​​​​​[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xP4FP/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Change eq(0) to this:

```
$('.config option:first-child').attr('selected', 'selected');​
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```js
$('.config').each(function(){ this.options[0].selected = 'selected'; });
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can only do it with the loop, otherwise it just updates the first one. http://jsfiddle.net/xP4FP/2/

```
$('.config option:eq(0)').each(function(i,el){$(el).attr('selected', 'selected')};
```